Is `__declspec(noalias)` a no-op?
gcc/clang's __attribute__((const)) is a close (but not entirely exact) analogue of msvc's __declspec(noalias): both express that "a function call doesn't modify or reference visible global state".  There are some differences in guarantees about parameters, but for a parameter-less function they're the same.
Anyway, I can see how gcc/clang use it. For example in this code-
void f(int* res) {
    res[0] = noGlobalAccess();
    res[1] = noGlobalAccess();
    res[2] = noGlobalAccess();
}

if noGlobalAccess is decorated with attribute((const)) these compilers deduce that it can be called only once, and have the result copied to the 3 dest slots. On msvc, no such optimization takes place and the call is made 3 times:
https://godbolt.org/z/5vM9MM8zb
So what is the case where __declspec(noalias) actually makes a difference?
(This answer doesn't provide a concrete example)

Although the descriptions of these do sound similar, they focus on different aspects of function behavior, consistent with their naming.  The description of __attribute__((const)) focuses on the return value being stable, such that calls to the function are candidates for common subexpression elimination.  The description of __declspec(noalias), on the other hand, focuses on the function's effects on memory and how the optimizer can rely on that.

Even if MSVC does not consider calls to a noalias function candidates for CSE, that does not mean __declspec(noalias) is useless.  The compiler can still assume that calls to a nullary noalias function don't change the values of any external objects.  That allows more kinds of optimization than just CSE.

And this is what the answer to the question you linked already says.  And it does give an example.  So what are you actually asking here that is not addressed there?

@JohnBollinger you're right, I missed the semantic meaning of the difference in jmp dest: https://godbolt.org/z/bqrvvda65

Here's possibly a clearer example, where the reference only needs to be read once because we know the noalias function can't change it: https://godbolt.org/z/MxTfo58ao
